# Including the Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to use a bit of code to cloud print with Google:

```
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('username', 'password', 'cloudprint');
        $Client_Login_Token = $client->getClientLoginToken(); 
        $client->setHeaders('Authorization','GoogleLogin auth='.$Client_Login_Token); 
        $client->setHeaders('X-CloudPrint-Proxy','Mimeo');

        $title = 'test';
        $fileUrl = 'url';
        $Printer_ID = 'ad83528c-a114-3f68-4768-c132ecc32ea2';


        $client->setUri('http://www.google.com/cloudprint/interface/submit');
        $client->setParameterPost('title', $title);
        $client->setParameterPost('content', $fileUrl );       
        $client->setParameterPost('contentType', 'url' ); 
        $client->setParameterPost('printerid', $Printer_ID); 
        $client->setParameterPost('capabilities', '{}' );
        $client->setConfig(array( 'timeout' => 180 ));          
        $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST); 
        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());
        var_dump($response);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin'
```

I'm using GoDaddy shared hosting. Is there just a file I can include_once that will contain this. I've downloaded the Zend framework but can't find the class?

Comment: Are you bootstraping whole zend application or you just trying use this part of Zend Framework? Did you download latest version of Zend Framework 1?

Comment: I just need it for this one part. I downloaded Zend 2. Is that why I can't find it?!

Comment: Yes, its in [Zend Framework 1](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/tree/master/library/Zend/Gdata). Check [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.introduction.html).

Comment: Can I just include the folder Gdata for this or do I need to upload the entire framework?

Comment: You can include only what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dowload the Zend Framework, put it into a directory on your server, add this directory to your include path.

Example

```
<?php
 $path = '/usr/lib/zend';
 set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
 ?>
```

Comment: Look like you are using version 1.x.
There is several dependencies with Zend.  You may need to use serveral packages